# Find $\int{\left({2x+1}\right)^3dx}$

Tags: integration

I want to find the following integral:

$$\int{\left({2x+1}\right)^3dx}$$

It was natural for me to develop it like this:

$$\int{(2x+1)(2x+1)(2x+1)}dx$$

And then find the integral from there. But looking at the solution that the textbook gives, which is

$$\frac {1}{8}{(2x+1)^4}+c$$

This makes me remeber of the formula:

$$\int{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha +1}$$

Therefore I tried to use it with the function but I only got

$$\frac{\left(2x+1\right)^4}{4}$$

This problem reminds me of the substitution rule but the textbook assumed I didn't know about it yet. Any hints on how to find the solution for the problem?

Comment: @User123456789 OP said: "This problem reminds me of the substitution rule but the textbook assumed **I didn't know about it yet.**"

Comment: without substitutions, you can simply factor out the brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the substition $u = 2x+1$.

Then $du = 2 dx$ and $dx = du/2$.

$\int (2x+1)^3 dx = \int (u)^3 (\frac{1}{2} du) = \frac{u^4}{8} + C =  \frac{(2x+1)^4}{8} + C$

Comment: Why did you use $\frac{1}{4}$ in your final answer and not $\frac{1}{8}$?

Comment: Mistake, thanks for telling

Answer (score 3):

In the question you have $(2x+1)^a$ bt in the formula you have $x^a$. So you have to do it by this formula instead: $$\int u^adu$$ Then $d(2x+1)=2dx$ so $\int (2x+1)^3dx$ would be $\int u^3\times du/2$ which is your first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Use identity
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$$

$$(2x+1)^3=8x^3+12x^2+6x+1$$

Comment: Good to see you bro. +

Comment: @mrs thanks....

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use substitution, you have to expand $(2x+1)^3$ and integrate the result.

$$\int{\left({2x+1}\right)^3dx} = \int (8x^3+12x^2+6x+1)dx $$

$$= 2x^4+4x^3+3x^2+x +C $$

Needless to say that the answer matches with $$\frac {(2x+1)^4}{8}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiation (using the **chain rule**) gives
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{(2x+1)^4}{4} = (2x+1)^3 \cdot 2
,
$$
where “times two” comes from the derivative of the inner function $2x+1$.
So your answer isn't correct; if you differentiate it, it gives twice what it's supposed to give. That's why you have to compensate by a factor of one half, so that you get 8 instead of 4 in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Use binomial coefficients for a more general answer:

$$\begin{align}\int (ax+b)^n & = \sum_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}\int (ax)^{n-k}b^k\\&= \sum_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n-k+1}\frac{1}{a}(ax)^{n-k+1}b^k + C\\&=\sum_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix}n+1\\k\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{a}(ax)^{n-k+1}b^k + C
\end{align}
$$
Which or the special case that $b=1$ becomes
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \begin{pmatrix}n+1\\k\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{a}(ax)^{n-k+1}b^k = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{a}(ax+b)^{n+1}$$
Then filling in $n=3$, $a=2$ , $b=1$ gives
$$\int (2x+1)^3 = \frac{1}{8}(2x+1)^4 +C$$

Comment: In this case, it would be great to specify under what conditions can you move from a "integral of sums" to a "sum of integrals".